# The name of a certain type of groups

Tags: group-theory, terminology

What is the name (if any) given to groups satisfying:

$$\forall x,y,z\in G [xyx^{-1}=(zxz^{-1})y(zxz^{-1})^{-1}]$$

I understand this question might not be suitable here, but I really can't search easily for the answer to the above question.

Comment: Seems suitable to me.

Comment: @GitGud Great :) I was afraid people would be worried that this might lead to questions like what is the name given to groups satisfying $xxyxzzzfgggx=fxxxygggggggggz$ for every $x,y,z,f,g$

Comment: This means that all members of the commutator subgroup commute with every element of $G$. Not sure how that helps find a name.

Comment: You mean that the condition you said is equivalent to mine or just a statement that is implied from my condition ?

Comment: Equivalent to your condition.

Comment: This then means that the commutator group is central and hence that the group is nilpotent of class at most $2$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be rewritten as:

$$(zx^{-1}z^{-1}x)y = y(zx^{-1}z^{-1}x)$$

Note that $zx^{-1}z^{-1}x$ can be any element of the generator set for the commutator subgroup, and it means that the generators of the commutator must commute will all elements of $G$. That means that *all* elements of the commutator subgroup commute with all elements of $G$.

So the commutator subgroup is a subgroup of the center of the group, or $[G,G]\subseteq Z(G)$.

Per Derek Holt's comment, this is called a [nilpotent group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group) of class $2$, or $2$-step nilpotent for short. (It's not clear if $2$-nilpotent includes $1$-nilpotent, which are commutative, but the commutative groups are also obviously included.)

Basically, we can easily show that $1\unlhd [G,G]\unlhd G$ is a [central series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_series) if and only if your condition is true.

And one [last link makes it explicit](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Group_of_nilpotency_class_two).

Comment: Yes I already verifed what you said by hand. I will try searching for that.

Comment: Such groups are called "nilpotent of class at most $2$", or "$2$-step nilpotent".

Comment: Added that to my answer (made it community wiki.) Thanks @DerekHolt

Comment: Note that Derek called it $2$-step nilpotent. $2$-nilpotent can mean something else (since there is a general concept of being $p$-nilpotent for any prime $p$, analogous to being $p$-solvable).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks, fixed.